# Am I subclassing my CSS correctly?

Tags: css, subclassing, css-cascade

I am making a set of buttons for my site, and I am in need of some professional insight.

In order to reduce CSS bloat, I want to subclass my buttons for different colors, *ex* .button.blue .

Will the following incur issues in the future? (assuming I don't make a class of just .blue) 
Do I have to use something like .button.button-blue instead?

```css
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 9px 18px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFE150;
}
.button.blue {
  background: #49b8e7;
  border:1px solid #54abcf;
  border-bottom:1px solid #398fb4;
  color:#FFF
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
}
.header{
  height: 50px;
}
.header.blue {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: There's no concept of *subclassing* in CSS. You can just *add* additional classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have there with the multi-classes will work fine assuming you want them to work like so:

```
<div class="button blue">
Will use .button and .button.blue
</div>

<div class="button">
Will only use .button
</div>

<div class="header blue">
Will  use .header and .header.blue
</div>

<div class="header">
Will only use .header
</div>

<div class="blue">
Will use neither of the .blue declarations because it doesn't contain header or button.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really got me thinking... the real con to my code above is if another dev makes a .blue class it will wreck the entire site. Where as .btn-blue will only be contained to that "module".

Comment: Exactly. It will definitely cause some issues if a standalone .blue is created.

Answer (score 1):

A selector like .button.blue actually selects for an element with that has both "blue" and "button" as classes, not a class called .button.blue. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html.

You can use the .button.blue style rule you have listed, but you'll need to rearrange your HTML so that you have something like `<button type="button" class="button blue"/>`. However, you don't really need to have a button class since it being a button (or `<input type="submit">`, etc.) is enough to use in your selector. You could write a CSS rule that is simply `button.blue, input[type=submit].blue{}`

Comment: Cool, I didn't think about adding the input[type=submit] like that =)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `button.blue` is enough.

The only difference between the two is if you use `<button class="button blue">`, or `<button class="button button-blue">`.

You even don't need to duplicate the painting in blue... You can just do something like this:

```
.button
{
// button style
}

.header
{
// header style
}

.blue
{
   background: blue; 
   color: #fff; 
}
```

Of course if you add the blue class to each of them. (`<div class="header blue">`and`<button class="button blue">`)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the classes applying the color you want to theme.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text-field-required default" .../>
<select class="autocomplete-drop-down blue">...</select>
<a href="#" class="button-link green" .../>
```

CSS:

```
.text-field-required {
    //component css theme without colors
}
.default {
    //default color css theme for any component
}
.blue {
    //blue css theme for any component
}
.green {
    //green css theme for any component
}
```